# How do I make a simple pageview counter in PHP that is universal to all pages?

Tags: php, web

I'm trying to have a line of `PHP` that counts all pageviews on any given post. The code will be `included` in each blog post with the authorbio.php.

So I'd like to have a pageview counter that says the number of pageviews on [current page].

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: *"How do I accomplish this?"* - Google's a safe bet as is trying something. Your question is both too broad and unclear.

Comment: use a database. text files are a major pain to maintain. You'd be setup under 10 mins.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple. If you want it for each post, just make a field in your database named something like "views." Every time the page loads, make a post request to your server to increment that views field by 1. Display that at the bottom. If you want to show a "live" counter, you can query the page count with ajax every so often and display the results from that.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to just keep a site page count, then all you need to do is store a number that goes up everytime the page loads. Have it persist by storing the number to a file or database. Retrieve, increment then update. If you need the counts to be specific to a page, then store the URL as well together with the count.

I guess you could also use something like google analytics to keep track of pageviews.

Comment: Google Analytics is great but I'd like to display the number of pageviews on each post. I guess I should have been more clear. I like the idea of storing the number in a txt file but I still have the issue of a dynamic script that can populate on all pages and report different numbers on each page without simply accumulating sitewide pageviews.

Comment: You should be able to interface with google analytics' API using their PHP client library to get the data to your site. There might be a learning curve if you've never used it before, but I think it would make for a great learning opportunity to play around with google data.

Comment: Oh that's perfect. The data is already there and I have a learning opportunity. Thanks!